# How to add Jbutton from another class to main class

Tags: java, jbutton

So am I trying to add JButton from another class into my main class, but I have no idea how to. Do I have to use a certain command or import a package to add the button?

```
//my first class with JButton
public class ScreenInitial
{
  public ScreenInitial()
  {
    JPanel  panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    JButton newArrival = new JButton("New Arrival");
    panel.add(newArrival);
  }
}



//my main class
public class FurryFriendsAnimalShelter extends JFrame
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("FFAS");
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    int widthScreen = ((int)tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
    int lengthScreen = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
    window.setSize(widthScreen,lengthScreen);
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    window.show(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to **extend some `JComponent` type** and let everything rely on that class.

```
public class NewClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Furry Friends Animal Shelter");
        Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        int widthScreen = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
        int lengthScreen = ((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth());
        window.setSize(widthScreen, lengthScreen);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        window.add(new ScreenInitial());
        window.show(true);
    }

    public static class ScreenInitial extends JPanel {

        public ScreenInitial() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
            JButton newArrival = new JButton("New Arrival");
            add(newArrival);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use JFrame#setExtendedState and pass it MAXIMISED_BOTH instead of Toolkit.getScreenSize, as it will take into consideration things like the task bar/dock. Use setVisible instead of show, show's been deprecated...for years. You should also start your UI within the context of the EDT

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for the advice! I was noticing a problem with my window size. Although, what do you mean by EDT?

Comment: Event Dispatching Thread - see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)